# Jasmine jQuery testing mouse enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

I am new to jasmine and jquery / javascript so I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here. Can you please help me?.

It seems it can't find the DOM element and can't perform the expected action correctly.

```
describe('ClickFunctions', function () {

    beforeEach(function () {
        jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = 'src/test/js/fixtures';
        loadFixtures('Click.html');
    });

    it('should change the css on mouseenter of step-header',function () {

        var step = $('#Step_1');

        step.trigger('mouseenter');

        expect(step).toHaveCss({
            'background-color': '#D9EDF7'
        })

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to load your styles too. Eg:

`loadStyleFixtures('css/stylesheet.css');`

And console log to see if `$('#Step_1')` exists. If it doesn't, then your fixture Click.hml might not have the necessary elements in it possibly. Hard to say without more information.

Here is the resources I found with related examples:

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/js-ref/testing-dom-events-using-jquery-and-jasmine-2.0.html

http://www.itsmycodeblog.com/jasmine-jquery-testing-css/